# How to detect Comprehend Service failure and test with SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

My application consumes many AWS services, and some services like Comprehend needs the region to be defined while building the client. I want to know specifically about Comprehend:

1. how to detect if the Comprehend Service has been failed in the  assigned region ?
2. Is there any specific exception thrown when the Comprehend Service is down?
3. Is there any operation/function in the SDK to check whether
   the Service is up and running ?
4. How to simulate a downtime of the service to test any error handling ?

I am using Java SDK. I know https://health.aws.amazon.com/health/status shows the current status, but would like to handle programmatically

Comment: See [AWS Health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/what-is-aws-health.html) and its [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/health-api.html).

Comment: Region failure is a bit strange. In the history of AWS, there has never been a "region failure", but there have been situations where certain services are failing in a region and this can also cause a cascade of problems. For example, if Lambda fails then any other service that relies on Lambda might fail, but other services will likely be working just fine. So, you'd be more interested to know whether the Comprehend service is available as opposed to whether "a region has failed".

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, Thanks for guidance. I updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status of Comprehend service using the AWS Health Dashboard which will provide you an overview of the service health.

https://health.aws.amazon.com/health/status

The Health Dashboard will provide you the details about the service health in the specific region. In case, you want to check the service health for all the region, you can check the following document which will provide you the details about the service health status of all AWS services in all region - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/APIReference/API_Health_ServiceHealth.html

As far as the SDK to check the status of the service is concerned, I recommend you to check the following document for the same - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/APIReference/API_Health_ServiceHealth.html

The SDK documentation will provide you the necessary details about the service health and the SDK to be used for the same.